# I am using JavaScript to acquire .png fingerprint image and verifying acquired fingerprint using .NET but it's not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, fingerprint, biometrics, digital-persona-sdk

I am using JavaScript SDK to acquire fingerprints using URU 4500 device and 3.2 Digital Persona SDK.  The image is .png and I am sending it to the server in base64.

On the server, the image is converted to bytes and it is given to `FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromRaw()` to generate FMD further, I am comparing 2 FMDs using `Compare()` method.

Javascript Code to acquire image:

```
localStorage.setItem("imageSrc", "");
    var samples = JSON.parse(s.samples);

    document.getElementById("fingerCounts").innerHTML = "Finger Counts = " + 
 enrollmentCount;
    if (identify) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Biometric/Compare',
            data: { fingerData:Fingerprint.b64UrlTo64(samples[0]), studentId: 1 },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === true)
                    alert('You are matched.');
                else {
                    alert('You are not matched');

                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the C# code where I am comparing two fingers one from DB and the other from request:

```
    public JsonResult Compare(string fingerData, int studentId)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fingerData);
        var storeData = _context.StudentBiometricData.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.StudentId == studentId);

        DataResult<Fmd> currentFinger = FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromRaw(bytes, 1, 
 3407615, 500, 550, 700, Constants.Formats.Fmd.ANSI);
        Fmd recorderFmd = Fmd.DeserializeXml(storeData.FingerFMD);


        CompareResult compareResult = Comparison.Compare(currentFinger.Data, 0, 
      recorderFmd,  1);

      
        return Json(false);
    }
```

When I create FMD from the raw images using `CreateFmdFromRaw` it mostly gives `DP_Faluir`. `Compare()` method returns INVAID_PARAMETER. Where I am doing something wrong? The provided sample WPF application is working fine it does not give any error and working perfectly fine. I think it's because I am using an image instead of FID?

Comment: did you find any way to use javascript with SDK?

Comment: @dmance no. I then created a small WPF application. Compare function will not work on web. Use their sample code for WPF. It wasted my lot of time then I moved to WPF

Comment: Do sad... I'm using java and javascript and I can not make it properly identify fingerprints :S

Comment: @dmance it is not good to attach fingerprint devices with the web app. You should create a small Java app and connect it to web API. They have a sample app for Java too if you have latest SDK.

Comment: actually I've found the way to do it properly. I have an Angular 13 application working with the digital persona 4500 and getting proper identification from the java backend. Right now I'm figuring how I can persist that data in a sql database :S

Comment: Keeping data in database is easy all you have to do is convert FMD to XML and save them as strings. There is a function that will let you convert to XML. You can read their docs.

Comment: JAva api does not have this funcionality, but I can convert to base64 the byte array of the FMD data

Comment: @dmance I am also trying to do same capture data using Web App and the store it into database. Later compare at backend. Can you please share the sample of your work?

Answer (score 0):

hey Any one achieved this "acquire .png fingerprint image and Add and verifying acquired fingerprint using .NET" in DigitalPersona.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34943837)